# Image load from URL increases size of cell in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell. Cell has a view with two labels on top & bottom. I am showing background image for the view. When I put a placeholder image then the size is normal but when I load any image from server then the size of cell is increased. I have given aspect fit to image view & height of imageview will be equal to the view.

Below is code for loading image:

```
func setImage(imageStringUrl:String) {        
    if self.imageView?.image == nil {
        let strUrl = APIHandler().baseURL.url + "storage/Admin/category/" + imageStringUrl
        DILog.print(items: "STRING URL \(strUrl)")
        let url = URL(string: strUrl)
        if url != nil {
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
            if let imageData = data {
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                self.imageOffer.image = image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try to set the image view height to a definite value? Also check if the automatic sizing is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

You have fixed its height and set content as aspect fit which is why based on its height, its size is being calculated due to aspect fit and resulting increase in cells size (because I am expecting you are setting automaticHeight for tableViewCell).

If you set content as center then you won't face this issue even if you set automatic height for tableViewCell.

If you set scaleToFill then also you won't face this issue.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check. Don't use the default imageView of a UITableViewCell. Add your own UIImageView by drag and dropping one into the cell. Particularly dont use the name as "imageView".

If that doesn't work, then compare your placeholder image and the image downloaded from server and try to find the size difference. Don't use images of size > 1024 x 1024. If the size it greater, then probably you need to resize them to fit in.

The other things tht u can try out:
-Check imgViewForCell.autoResizingMask set to UIViewAutoResizingNone.

-Set imgViewForCell.clipsToBounds to YES